# I am trying to store in HDFS as parquet file from teradata with help of TDCH jar 1.6 version

Tags: parquet

I am trying to store in HDFS as parquet file  from teradata with help of TDCH jar

I am getting connection exception : plugin "hdfs-parquet" not found

How can i resolve the issue?

Comment: I am using TDCH1.6 version,which will support parquet format as well,I hope TDCH 1.5 is supporting AVRO and text file only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do that since TDCH does not have that feature available.  Parquet support is for Hive, so you need to have a hive table which is stored as parquet and then use TDCH with job type hive and file format as parquet.

If you are wanting to store the data from TD to HDFS as parquet, then you would need to use sqoop with jdbc connection and use --as-parquetfile option and not use CLDR or HWX TD wrapper.